# Why Android app rollout to production failed?

Tags: android, developer-console

My android app is removed from google play store because of the `targetSdkVersion` policy change. I updated my app to meet the `targetSdkVersion`. I'm at the end of the  rollout to production. When I hit "**START ROLLOUT TO PRODUCTION**" button and confirm, it says "*The rollout of your releases failed. Check the page for validation errors.*" I don't see any validation error on that page. Any idea what is going wrong?
[image]

Comment: Is there any message showing from that triangular error icon?

Comment: At version 1 min api 8 but in v2 19+ a huge difference. You may need to eye on this and current active devices is only 13 which all are may be below 19.

Comment: what does it says in validation error ?

Comment: The yellow triangle is simply a warning saying lower version of android will not be able to use the app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally google team found that I haven't selected **Primarily Child-Directed** option under **Pricing & distribution**. It was not there earlier. Hence nothing is selected. Now it is a required field. The red error banner is just not clear to know where is error.
[image]

Comment: It should tell you what the error is. Specifically, it lies when it says the error is on the page. In my case, it was under App Content.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helps me to find my issue.

Comment: Thanks! In my case was "App content" also under "Store presence"